# Numpy power with array as exponent

Tags: python, numpy, factorial, poisson

I have a Python code containing the following lines:

```
# Poisson model

lambda_param = 3.0

x_model = numpy.linspace(0, 10, num=11, dtype=int)
y_model = numpy.zeros(10)

index = 0
for x in x_model:
    y_model[index] = numpy.power(lambda_param, x) / math.factorial(x) * numpy.exp(-lambda_param)
    index += 1
```

I want to write this in a more Pythonic way - without using a for loop.

I tried this:

```
y_model = numpy.power(lambda_param, x_model) / math.factorial(x_model) * numpy.exp(-lambda_param)
```

But this didn't seem to work, I would guess because `math.factorial` doesn't know how to operate on an array like object.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `numpy.linspace(0, 10, num=10)` gives `array([ 0. ,  1.11111111,  2.22222222, 3.33333333,  4.44444444, 5.55555556,  6.66666667,  7.77777778,  8.88888889, 10. ])`. What's factorial of 2.22222222?

Comment: Was that just a guess, or did the error message explicitly tell you there was a problem with the `math` function.?

Comment: @MariaK sorry that's a good spot - I've updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the `pmf` for a poisson distribution. Use [`scipy.stats.poisson`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.poisson.html):
Note that for poisson, `x` must be integers:

```
lambda_param = 3.0
x_model = np.arange(10)
y_model = np.zeros(10)

from scipy import stats
stats.poisson(lambda_param).pmf(x_model)
array([0.04978707, 0.14936121, 0.22404181, 0.22404181, 0.16803136,
       0.10081881, 0.05040941, 0.02160403, 0.00810151, 0.0027005 ])
```

Comment: pmf is presumably the same as pdf?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Essentially yes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function. Strictly speaking, they're distinct, but they behave analogously for discrete vs continuous RVs

Comment: Yes of course, there's a subtle difference because the distribution is discrete. You can get a true PDF by multiplying by a delta function

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`scipy.special.factorial`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.factorial.html) as a factorial function that supports broadcasting over numpy arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.special

>>> scipy.special.factorial(np.arange(7))
array([  1.,   1.,   2.,   6.,  24., 120., 720.])
```